# HTML5 Manifest fallback URL

Tags: html, cache-manifest

I have a website which in a DEV context has the URL localhost:8080/MySite
and on test/live it will just be www.test.mysite.com and www.mysite.com

In my manifest i have

```
FALLBACK:
/ offline.html
```

the problem is if the user hits `localhost:8080/MySite` (not no slash on end) and the fallback kicks in they get redirected to `localhost:8080MySite` which bugs...

Does anyone know around this issue, I tried `/ /offline.html` but that bugged the manifest

Comment: It works fine when any page on the website is accessed or if "/MySite/" is used. It's just when you try access the root page without a slash at the end. Can anyone think how I can get around this? I'm serving the website in JSP and it has the context "MySite"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to replicate your case as much as I could. It worked fine for me using the following:

- I have a directory structure like this one:

  /MySite/HTML/

  /MySite/Styles/

  /MySite/Images/

  /MySite/Scripts/

All my HTML files are located under */MySite/HTML/*, including "offline.htm"

- My manifest file is as follows:

  CACHE MANIFEST

  CACHE:
  main.htm

  /MySite/Styles/mustyles.css

  /MySite/Images/random.jpg

  /MySite/Scripts/jquery.js

  NETWORK:

  *

  FALLBACK:

  / /MySite/HTML/offline.htm

If I type the Following URLs, I always get the "offline.htm" page:

- localhost/MySite/
- localhost/MySite
- localhost/MySite/HTML/
- localhost/MySite/HTML

Note the fallback URL. Tested on FF and Chrome.

Hope this helps.